# What's the equivalent of mysql RLIKE operator in Hibernate Query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, rlike

I have the following query which runs perfectly in mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders as o, Products as p  where o.productinfo RLIKE p.code;
```

Here I am joining two tables Orders and Products with RLIKE.

I am trying to implement the same in Hibernate.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Orders as o, Products as p  where o.productinfo RLIKE p.code");
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

When I used RLIKE, the following error is thrown in run time.

```
{"errormessage":"org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: RLIKE
```

I tried to implement the same with LIKE query and matched it with '%p.code%'.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Orders as o, Products as p  where o.productinfo LIKE '%p.code%'");
```

But it matches with the string "p.code" rather then the value.

What is the equivalent of RLIKE in HQL? 
Is there a different way to join two tables with LIKE in HQL?

Thanks.

Answer by @YCF_L:
For any one trying to join two tables with like operator in Hibernate (mysql) can do it the following way.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders as o, Products as p  where o.productinfo LIKE CONCAT('%',p.code,'%');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the equivalent of mysql RLIKE operator in Hibernate Query?

**RLIKE** is the synonym for `REGEXP` so you can implement it in hibernate using `REGEXP_LIKE`, you can take a look about this here : [How to search in multiple columns using one like operator in HQL (hibernate sql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758411/how-to-search-in-multiple-columns-using-one-like-operator-in-hql-hibernate-sql/42759069#42759069)

---

> I tried to implement the same with LIKE query and matched it with
>   '%p.code%'.
>
> ```
> ..., Products as p  where o.productinfo LIKE '%p.code%'");
> ```
>
> But it matches with the string "p.code" rather then the value.

This is true, because you don't pass the correct value of `p.code`, you pass it like a String, instead you have two ways :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("....Products as p  where o.productinfo LIKE '%:code%'");
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^
query.setParameter("code", p.code);
```

Or you can concatenate your code with your Query, but the first solution is better.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("....  where o.productinfo LIKE '%" + p.code + "%'");
```

---

**EDIT**

You can use like with CONCAT without specify the `''` like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Orders as o, Products as p  where o.productinfo LIKE CONCAT('%',p.code,'%');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I couldn't still solve the issue. Is there a way to join two tables with like ? Here "p.code" is a column from a table to be joined rather than a static value.

Answer (score 0):

You can check regular expression way something like this way:     Restrictions.sqlRestriction(word REGEXP '^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$')

Please check the link which will be helpful for this case: [Regular expression with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747770/regular-expression-with-criteria)